# Serve dockerized ZendFramework2 Application with nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I want to Dockerize a **ZendFramework2** Application with Nginx, Mysql, and PHP7.

When I run `docker-compose up` all containers are built. But When I want to access `localhost:8080` I get the nginx default page although the `default.conf` was replaced by my `site.conf`. A restart of the nginx container hasn't changed anything.

*Because this is my first try of dockerizing an Application I would also like to get feedback on my docker-setup*

I Followed [this](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/) Tutorial, but it doesn't work either in its simplest form.

You could use my [Example Application](https://github.com/takethefake/dockerizeZendStackoverflow) to reproduce this behaviour.

Thanks in Advance for your help

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ferienhof
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ferienhof
      MYSQL_USER: ferienhof
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ferienhof

  web:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
      - ./resources/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
volumes:
    db_data:
```

> Dockerfile for php

*php.ini taken from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/master/php.ini-production)*

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    cron \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libxslt1-dev

# Configure the gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-configure \
  gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/

# Install required PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
  gd \
  intl \
  mbstring \
  mcrypt \
  pdo_mysql \
  xsl \
  zip \
  soap

# Install the 2.4 version of xdebug that's compatible with php7
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug-2.4.0

COPY resources/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

  # Install composer and put binary into $PATH
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install phpunit and put binary into $PATH
RUN curl -sSLo phpunit.phar https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-old.phar \
    && chmod 755 phpunit.phar \
    && mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

# Install PHP Code sniffer
RUN curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar \
    && chmod 755 phpcs.phar \
    && mv phpcs.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpcs.phar /usr/local/bin/phpcs \
    && curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcbf.phar \
    && chmod 755 phpcbf.phar \
    && mv phpcbf.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpcbf.phar /usr/local/bin/phpcbf
```

> resources/site.conf

```
server {
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    listen       80;
    root         /code/public;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location @php {
        # Pass the PHP requests to FastCGI server (php-fpm) on 127.0.0.1:9000
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /code/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: recognised that I have to change fastcgi_pass to php:9000 to enable the link, but now the nginx returns the raw php-file. Seems like the php-Container has not processed the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my docker-compose a little. The working files can be found at http://git.schulz.codes/bootstrap/docker-php/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx config uses `php-docker.local` as `server_name`, but you're accessing the site with the name `localhost`.